# Can items with most common descendants be found using SQL / MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Can SQL be used to find all the brands that has the most common categories?

For example, the brand "Dove" can have category of Soap, Skin Care, Shampoo
It is to find all the brands that has the most matching categories, in other words, the most similar brands.

It can be done programmatically using Ruby or PHP: just take a brand, and loop through all the other brands, and see how many matching categories there are, and sort by it.   But if there are 2000 brands, then there needs to be 2000 queries per brand.  (unless we pre-cache all the 2000 query results, so for all 2000 brands, we re-use those results)

Can it be done by SQL / MySQL by 1 query?

Say, the table has:

```
entities
--------
id
type =  brand or category or product
name


entities_parent_child
--------------------
parent_id
child_id
```

the table above has an entry for each parent = brand and child = product, and also an entry for each parent = category and child = product, so brand has to relate to category by products.

I think the hard part for SQL is: find all the maximum matching counts, and sort by those numbers.

Comment: This is bad database design - what you describe is not a real parent/child relationship, where you can an indefinite number of parents/children. It's pretty much always bad practice to create something so generic as an `entities` table.

Comment: The main problem is that MySQL doesn't have hierarchical query support.

Comment: @wuputah I think the DB originally contained only Products, Categories, and Brands table.  But storing them in entity table can reuse some common functions and have them as polymorphic in terms of parent / child relation in a tree.  But what if they are in 3 separate tables, is there a way to find similar brands using 1 SQL statement (or a few)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with wuputah's comment. For this problem an "entities" table is not the answer. You've given yourself a hint the design is wrong when you say you cannot form a query to get the answers you want.

Create a proper hierarchy for your data, with separate tables for separate real word entities, yours will be:

```
[Brands] 
[Categories]
[Products]
```

If you need help with defining trees and hierarchies in SQL I suggest you pick up a copy of Celko's [Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).

SQL has no concept of polymorphism so don't try to design your database to fit your programming language. Databases work with sets, so think in sets.

To find similar brands join your tables and use grouping:

```
SELECT Brands.brand_name, COUNT(Categores.category_name) as category_count
FROM Brands INNER JOIN Categories
ON Brands.brand_name = Categories.brand_name
GROUP BY Brands.brand_name
ORDER BY Brands.brand_name, COUNT(Categores.category_name) -- add DESC if you want largest count at the top
```

That gives you the basic idea, if you can expand on the requirement:

> ...find all the maximum matching
>   counts, and sort by those numbers

Then I can help redesign the query and, if necessary, the schema design.

Comment: isn't it true you can always substitute the Product table with the entity table but just use `select ... from ... entity as p ... where entity_type = "Product"` instead of `select ... from ... product as p`?

Comment: In some, small, databases you can use EAV tables to good effect but in your case why do you want to? You have distinct entities (Brands, Categories & Products) so why not put them in their own tables? The entity model means you cannot enforce data integrity and you end up joining the table to itself many times, reducing performance. Have a look at this interesting article: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx